# XML to csv using c#

Tags: c#, c#-5.0

I'm working on an application I click the upload button I select the xml file and I want That a time I click on the button generate csv I want the file to be generate
Here is an example of an XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<W-TIBCPTRs>
  <W-TIBCPTR>
    <TYPTRT>FDR2 R</TYPTRT>
    <CLAFCNO VALIDE="NON">5b1</CLAFCNO>
    <NUMCLI>0067781</NUMCLI>
    <TYPACT>D</TYPACT>
  </W-TIBCPTR>
  <W-TIBCPTR>
    <TYPTRT>FDR2 R</TYPTRT>
    <CLAFCNO>511</CLAFCNO>
    <NUMCLI>0068078</NUMCLI>
    <TYPACT>D</TYPACT>
  </W-TIBCPTR>
</W-TIBCPTRs>
```

Comment: The downvote is because of not showing us what you have tried, and what is failing. If you are asking for someone to write the code for you, then I'm affraid you've come to the wrong place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for something like the following snippet, but that conversion have some problem with node attributes

```
string p = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                  "<W-TIBCPTRs>" +
                    "<W-TIBCPTR>" +
                      "<TYPTRT>FDR2 R</TYPTRT>" +
                      "<CLAFCNO VALIDE=\"NON\">5b1</CLAFCNO>" +
                      "<NUMCLI>0067781</NUMCLI>" +
                      "<TYPACT>D</TYPACT>" +
                    "</W-TIBCPTR>" +
                    "<W-TIBCPTR>" +
                      "<TYPTRT>FDR2 R</TYPTRT>" +
                      "<CLAFCNO>511</CLAFCNO>" +
                      "<NUMCLI>0068078</NUMCLI>" +
                      "<TYPACT>D</TYPACT>" +
                    "</W-TIBCPTR>" +
                  "</W-TIBCPTRs>";
      XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(p);

      var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
      foreach (var o in doc.Descendants("W-TIBCPTR"))
      {
        var TYPTRT = o.Element("TYPTRT").Value;
        var CLAFCNO = o.Element("CLAFCNO").Value;
        var NUMCLI = o.Element("NUMCLI").Value;
        var TYPACT = o.Element("NUMCLI").Value;
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", TYPTRT, CLAFCNO, NUMCLI, TYPACT));
      }
```